# Usage du subjonctif avec la conjonction de subordination « que » et une fréquence

Tags: subjonctif

Bonjour,

Dans cette phrase :

> Il est fréquent que quelqu'un soit si courageux qu'il prenne son courage à deux mains.

Un de mes professeurs m'a indiqué qu'il était possible (et plutôt conseillé) d'utiliser l'indicatif, car le subjonctif impliquait que l'action n'était pas réalisée, mais seulement son envisagement. Il faudrait donc plutôt écrire :

> Il est fréquent que quelqu'un soit si courageux qu'il prend son courage à deux mains.

L'exemple est plutôt bateau, mais soit. Il me semble bizarre d'utiliser l'indicatif ici, étant donné qu'il y a une question de fréquence ici. Quelqu'un serait-il capable de trancher sur cette question, ou tout du moins de la nuancer ?

Answer (score 1):

Il faut toujours le subjonctif après la construction « il est fréquent que ».

[français facile](https://www.francaisfacile.com/forum/lire.php?num=7&msg=66721&titre=Subjonctif%3F)

[études littéraires](https://www.etudes-litteraires.com/grammaire/subjonctif-formes-impersonnelles.php)

Comment: Oui mais la seconde proposition peut-elle ou pas être à l'indicatif ? J'avoue que intuitivement je dirais non, ca ne "sonne" pas bien, mais je ne trouve aucun exemple pour infirmer/affirmer cela...

Comment: @LaurentS. Selon une certaine logique il faut le subjonctif mais je ne trouve pas l'usage (pas d'exemples). Puisque la condition d'être courageux est sujette à l'incertitude, ce qui en découle doit l'être aussi, mais ce n'est pas un principe de logique par « a plus b ». Il existe bien des cas dans l'ancien français, par exemple celui-ci, mais il date du début du XVIIième siècle : https://books.google.fr/books?id=y4cQ7ixzSMoC&pg=RA5-PA61&dq=%22qu%27il+soit+si%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjM5OvEkcjsAhWKkhQKHSnbC8wQ6AEwDHoECDUQAg#v=onepage&q=%22qu'il%20soit%20si%22&f=false.

Comment: Quoi qu'il en soit, le conseil de ce professeur (cfr question) semble assez audacieux...

Answer (score 1):

La première proposition concerne effectivement une notion de fréquence, une éventualité, et le subjonctif est de mise.

Le deuxième subjonctif utilisé ici concerne uniquement l'attribut du sujet. La proposition "si courageux qu'il prend son courage à deux mains" exprime un fait établi : s'il est courageux, il prend forcément son courage à deux mains. Donc indicatif, pour exprimer cette "certitude".

Ce n'est peut-être pas très rigoureux grammaticalement comme explication, mais c'est un bon moyen pour choisir entre subjonctif et indicatif lorsque les deux peuvent être corrects.

Un autre exemple, dans le cas de paroles rapportées :

- "Il m'a dit qu'il **irait** à la gare le lendemain" exprime un *relatif* doute sur le fait que la personne ira bien à la gare (dû au fait qu'il ne s'agit que de paroles rapportées, et d'une action envisagée).
- "Il m'a dit qu'il **ira** à la gare le lendemain" exprime un degré de certitude important sur le fait que cette personne fera bien comme il a dit.